# Preloader load all assets before launching HTML Site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, preloader

I am currently creating a simple HTML page. The page contains an image, audio and a background video. The page is quite large (total 5-6 MB). So I want to do a preloader that loads all the assets and then launches the HTML site. I only found animated preloaders that fade out after a certain time - not when the full content with all the assets is ready.

Do you have any idea what the Javascript for such a preloader would look like?

Here's my code - all not necessary (like meta tags) removed. I already prepared a CSS and JS File:

```css
#backgroundvideo {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/master.css">
    <link rel="script" href="/js/preloader.js">
  </head>

  <body>
    
    <!-- Video -->
    <video autoplay muted loop id="backgroundvideo">
      <source src="/media/joetnar-backgroundvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

    <!-- Logo -->
    <div class="content">
      <img src="/media/joetnar-logo-200.png" alt="JOETNAR Logo" title="JOETNAR Logo">
    </div>

    <!-- Audio -->
    <iframe src="/media/joetnar-intro.mp3" allow="autoplay" style="display:none" id="iframeAudio">
    </iframe>

  </body>

</html>
```

The audio is loaded via iframe because of the new google "no audio autoplay" policy. This is a light workaround since iframes can still start automaticly.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Fade out the loader using `onload` on body tag or inside `#(window).load()` in jquery

Comment: I would load the page and replace an image with the loaded video when ready/loaded. I would not start with audio on, as it is not a nice thing to do (for the user). Preloaders are not very good for SEO and conversion either. Still want to do it? Note that onload handlers have the risk of not firing (because of possible 404's). A fixed amount of seconds is safer.

Comment: @JoostS Thanks for the advice! I think in this case I don't want to do it that way anymore. I'm gonna try your solution. I'm thinking of making a button for automuted sound on / off like on 9gag or facebook.

Answer (score 0):

the Javascript for a preloader would look like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(window).load(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#preloader').fadeOut('slow', function() {});
    }, 2000);

  });
});
```

Comment: @Lenonid Volkov: Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hey Leonid, I'm just playing around with this but the problem still is:

The video takes a lot time to buffer. The page shows up and the video still needs to load fully. I want the preloader to disappear after the video is fully buffered. Any idea how to do this event handler in jQuery?